# Classifier can predict time series 1 day in advance, but not more. Why?

Tags: time-series, boosting, precision-recall, sensitivity-specificity, f1

To ask the question more precisely: when doing Time Series classification, I observe the classifier prediction is good if test data directly follows (in chronology) the train data. But when the train and test sets are separated in time (even by very small amount of records), the performance falls dramatically fast. Is this the expected behavior? Below are all the details:

I am working on timeseries classification. My timeseries data describe certain events in time. I have about 60 events (records) daily. These events have about 30 features and a binary label: 0/1. I need to predict this label.

The typical ratio of 1/0 is roughly 0.3/0.7, so essentially on an average day I expect 20 ones and 40 zeros. Thus the classes are unbalanced (imbalanced).
I have 84 days of data that can be used as train/test. This maps to 5,000 records.

My classifier is XGBoost, because in several previous experiments it worked best. I also understand that it performs well in unbalanced set scenarios.
I also make sure the records are sorted chronologically and that train and test sets are correctly split and separated in time: the train set is always before test set.
The success metrics is F1_score (both precision and recall are important).

**Now, the problem is as follows:**

After many experiments I have gotten to reasonable results: F1 = .73, with classifier trained on 2500 records (40 days of data). This is an average number, because the same classifier tested on different test days will of course yield variable results. And here lies the issue. I wanted to see how exactly these results differ between particular test days. By examining closer these daily results, I saw they were not uniform: the results were much better if the tested day directly followed the train set. For instance (Diagram 1 below), when the train set consisted of data from 15 May-15 June, then the classifier would perform best on 16 June's data and then rapidly fall.[image: Diagram 1]

I suspected this was to do with the data, especially that the ratio of C1 class (shown by dotted line on diagrams) was slightly different on various days. So I fixed this, by purposely downsampling the test data, day by day, to the same ratio that the train set had (about 0.3, as stated earlier). I then run more tests and saw that this phenomenon was not specific to any particular day, but happened always.

Diagram 2 shows the classifier trained on 1000 records (16 days) of data, and then tested on 28 days that follow directly the test set. So, the train + test batch had the total of 44 days of data. This experiment has then been repeated 40 times: First covering the beginning (initial 44 days) of the available 84-day data set, and then each time the train+test batch has been shifted by 1 day into the future. So eventually all the data was covered. Diagram 2 below shows the averaged results. Now the trend is clear and the hypothesis confirmed: the results (precision and recall) are always better on day following the test set, regardless of the date (or day of week). Then they systematically drop, especially the recall[image: Diagram 2]

Diagram 3 shows the same experiment, with different parameters: classifier trained on 3,000 records (48 days of data), tested on 10 days, and the experiment repeated 26 times (note I don't have more data: 48 + 10 + 26 = 84). We can see that the results are somewhat better (because the classifier had more data for train), but the trend persists: the performance is always best on the day following the train set.[image: Diagram3]

While this behavior can be accepted in general, I feel something is very wrong here. I understand that the data may change over time (data drift) and so the performance of predictions are generally expected to worsen with time. But the rate of this is too fast. For example, have a look how quickly Recall (sensitivity) drops, in Diagram 3: I trained the classifier over 48 days. Then, if tested on day 49, recall is 0.61, but tested only 5 days later it drops below 0.4. My naive reasoning is this: given that the train period was 48 days, the test data variability, if any, should not be so dramatically visible to confuse the classifier so quickly.

But the experiments prove otherwise. I feel I am doing something wrong. A methodology error? Any hints or ideas welcome.

**Edit4.8.2020:** To clarify even more, I want to explain the meaning of the data. My data describe events (technical incidents) that happen in the certain network infrastructure. 1 record = 1 incident, e.g. a hard drive crash. The label (target) 0/1 means importance. In great simplification, an event is important (1) if it is likely to cause more trouble in near future if not fixed immediately. We know which events in the past turned to be important (they indeed did cause more trouble later on), and those have been labelled 1. So, the business goal of the classification is to distinguish important events (1) from unimportant ones (0) early in the game, and pass this information to the team who then prioritizes the fixing work accordingly. As stated, on an average day we have 20 important events and 40 unimportant ones.

Comment: It could be an example of [tag:concept-drift]. There can be any number of causes for this. Perhaps the nature of the task changes over time.

Comment: Have you tried comparing to the trivial "classifier" where $\hat y_t = y_{t-1}$ ? How do the results compare?

Comment: @Tim, thanks. An interesting thought, and I am ready to try. But what would be the purpose of this exercise. What is the hypothesis we would be proving/disproving?

Comment: @Sycorax thank you, for clarity I just edited the post adding last paragraph, where I described the meaning of the data. I do not have a string feeling why concept drift could take place, but I may simply lack experience. If you have hints I'll gladly listen and explore. I looked at the link you provided but didn't find much articles with that tag.

Comment: @DataMan maybe your algorithm has learned to do exactly this? Than it would work one day in advance, but not further. This would suggest that it is wasteful to use the model you are using since it doesn't outperform the trivial model.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer thanks to the thoughtful comments by @Pawel and @Tim. Their both suggested that there must be an implicit close chronological relationship between the data located closely in time, so that yesterday test data (part of train) may be related to today's data (part of test). This was key inspiration, allowing me to discover the problem.

The problem was in the label (target variable). As explained in the post, the meaning of the label 1 was that an event was important, meaning: it will cause problems in the *future*. Yes, future... Events labelled 1 were those that had documented causal effect up to 7 days in advance. So the label had implicitly allowed the classifier to peak up to 7 days in the future.

And here is how it worked: when test set was very close to train set, the classifier could cheat, because the test events labelled 1 were similar or even identical to the very recent train events, which it has already seen and learned. Separating the train and test sets by 7 days made that cheating impossible, so the performance dropped.

I may be able to post more when the solution has been documented, for now just this quick explanation to let everyone know what the nature of the problem was. @Pawel and @Tim, thank you. Very impressive insight.

Comment: +1 Thanks for follow-up. It is a good practice to share your results like this. Maybe you could add plots showing old vs new results, or more details how did you discover it, as an illustration? It would be interesting to see more details, especially since you're not the first one, and not the last one to have such problem.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it that testing on data that follows directly the train data is almost like testing on train dataset? I mean, depending on the nature of your data but probably there is a small difference between train data on day x and test data on day x+1 and that is why you have good results at the beginnig.

Comment: Thanks. No, I do not think this is the case. My data describe incidents (problems) that happen in the network infrastructure. 1 record = 1 incident, e.g. a hard drive crash. The label (target) 0/1 means importance (in great simplification). We want to distinguish important events (1) from unimportant ones (0). So, suppose we had certain mix of events over 48 days (daily average being 60 records). I agree that on day 49th the mix could be similar. But I don't see why on day 52 it should be significantly different. What do you think?

Comment: If you do the excercise proposed by @Tim you will see how dynamically your target changes. If this naive method will show good result than I would bet that this the way your algorithm works.

Comment: My thinking is that your features are mostly built on past observations of time series itself, like average of the last hour, day, week. If this is the case then features that describe label on day 48th are almost the same
as features that describe the day 49th. Then, these observations cannot be seen as idependent and as an side effect it is highly probable that your algorithm just passes the observations from previous day on the next day.
Besides @Tim's proposal I would also check the feature importance and apply XAI methods to shed some light on algorithm's internals.

Comment: Pawel and @Tim, I got your thought now. Very plausible hypothesis! essentially you are proposing that some of my features may intrinsically contain aggregated statistical information pertaining to the past period. This could really well explain the behavior observed. Very clever and thoughtful! I am stuck with another project today but will soon make a test and get back to you on this. Meanwhile, any other suggestions are very welcome. I'll look at each one carefully.